# How to pass a variable value from one xhtml to another xhtml and then to the backing ManagedBean of 2nd xhtml

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, managed-bean

I am working on a JSF project. It's using **JSF-2** version.

I have a `test.xhtml` which includes another XHTML, below is the code:-

```
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/genericTag.xhtml" >
                <ui:param name="cache" value="ProjectQueryCache"></ui:param>
            </ui:include>
```

I passed ***ProjectQueryCache*** value via the variable **cache**. In the `genericTag.xhtml` is having below piece of code:-

```
    <ui:composition 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
        
        <p:dataTable id="genericId" var="queryRow"
                value="#{genericManagedBean.fetchQueryList()}" style="margin-bottom:40px"
                scrollable="true" scrollWidth="100%" scrollHeight="350" rows="10"
                paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{Previous} {Next} "  >
                
                <f:facet name="header">
                       <h:outputText value="Projects" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:16; color:#336699"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="{Previous}">
                       <p:commandButton value="Previous" actionListener="#{genericDatatableManagedBean.previous()}" />
                </f:facet>
    
                <f:facet name="{Next}">
                       <p:commandButton value="Next" actionListener="#{genericDatatableManagedBean.next()}" />
                </f:facet>
    
                <f:param name="cacheName" id="cacheName" value="#{cache}" />
                
                <p:column headerText="Project id"  sortBy="#{queryRow.project_id}" filterBy="#{queryRow.project_id}" 
                    filterMatchMode="contains" width="100" style="font-size:9PT">
                    <h:outputText value="#{queryRow.project_id}" />
                </p:column>
    
                <p:column headerText="Project name"  sortBy="#{queryRow.project_name}" filterBy="#{queryRow.project_name}" 
                    filterMatchMode="contains" width="100" style="font-size:9PT">
                    <h:outputText value="#{queryRow.project_name}" />
                </p:column>
                
             </p:dataTable> 
    </ui:composition >
```

But in the managedBean `GenericManagedBean` of the genericTag.xhtml, I am not getting the value of variable **#{cache}** in `f:param`, it's always coming as **null**.
Below is the managedBean code,

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "genericManagedBean")
    @SessionScoped
    public class GenericManagedBean implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
       
       public void fetchQueryList() {
            try {
                FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
                Map<String, String> params = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();
                String name = params.get("cacheName");
                System.err.println(name);
                System.out.println("fetchQueryList() - ended....");
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Throwable cause = e.getCause();
                throw new ELException(cause);
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Please suggest to me how to fix this issue.
I checked this answer already here, [f:param is null in bean jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555430/fparam-is-null-in-bean-jsf) , but it's not working for me. Any help?

Comment: ui:param != f:param

Comment: @BalusC what's the difference?